# How do I fix my emulator screen being much bigger than the actual working screen?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-emulator

Don't remember changing anything at all, and suddenly when I opened Android Studio today (running it through the AVD Manager), it did this. How do I fix it? [As you can see, workspace is much much smaller than emu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sffO.png)

Edit: Just in case it is somehow related, the emulator always gives me a "adb not found" error. Never seemed to mess with anything I did, so ignored it.

Comment: Have you try another emulator

Comment: Haven't, for which I'll have to delete this one and reinstall another 8 gigs, but trying to see if I can solve this without reinstalling.

Comment: Just download another one

Comment: Tried, hasn't worked.